# Looking for a replacement for Instamapper

Tags: gps, gps.net

I've been searching the net for a couple days now and haven't turned up anything that solves my issue.

The current client I'm working for currently embeds Instamapper into thier site which allows them to track thier drivers in real-time.

now my search has produced a good number of GPS tracking solutions but none that meet all the requirements the client is looking for, so I decided to post the question on here and see if anyone knows anything that I may have missed.

*Requirements* 
Must be able to embed a map into the clients site.
Must be compatible with Blackberry, Android, and iPhone mobile Phones.
Doesn't have to be free, the Client is willing to pay for the service.

If anyone knows of a solution I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you,
BWC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and searched, and there really isn't anything out there that solved my problem so I ended up writing my own.